# Date Format incorrect after select date

Tags: kendo-ui

I'm using (k-format = "dd/MM/yyyy") to set date formate of kendo-date-picker, so, after date selected the format was not respected. I tried to use (k-options ="dateTimePickerOptions") making

> $scope.dateTimePickerOptions = { format: "dd/MM/yyyy" }

it worked, but before sending data to the server, i checked out the data on scope and the console.log returned "Invalid Date".

this is my complete code:

> input name="data"  kendo-date-picker  ng-model="item.Data" 
>   k-ng-model="dateObject"  style="width: 100%;"  placeholder="Select a
>   date"  k-options ="dateTimePickerOptions" k-parse-formats
>   ="['yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:sszzz']" required />

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
<script>
    jQuery.extend(jQuery.validator.methods, {
        date: function (value, element) {
            return this.optional(element) || kendo.parseDate(value, "dd/MM/yyyy") != null;
        }
    });

</script>
```

View

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}
@model DatePickerValidation.Models.ViewModel

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @( 
        Html.Kendo().DatePickerFor(model => model.MyDate).Format("dd/MM/yyyy")
        .ParseFormats(new List<string>()
                        {
                        "dd/MM/yyyy",
                        "dd/MM/yy",
                        "dd MMM yyyy"
                        })
        .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-datetimepicker" })
    )
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MyDate)

    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
}
```

ViewModel

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace DatePickerValidation.Models
{
    public class ViewModel
    {
        public DateTime MyDate { get; set; }
    }
}
```